# Socket.setPerformancePreferences in Java 1.8

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

What exactly does this method do, can someone break down in laymen terms what each thing really means and benefits. It is my understanding this method had no implementation in Java 1.6 is this still true for Java 1.8?

Comment: What it does is going to be somewhat implementation specific.  According to the Android documents, it currently does nothing.

Comment: @GabeSechan That is a bummer, how about for desktop? When I read the doc it sounds like a very important feature but then I found out 1.6 has no code implementation. Does it do anything for Desktop?